# Joining a major road to A64 to Leeds from a small road

Tags: uk, automobiles, road-signs

Please let me know how to approach and join this major road A64 to Leeds from York.

My car is coming as the yellow line highlighted. There is no give way sign(there is only one broken line) in the central reservation(red ellipse). I understand we should be giving way to the traffic coming from my left. Should I be aiming for the left lane or the right lane(green or orange line?) after I join?

1. if i aim for left lane(normal lane) there will be a lot of vehicles in that lane as it is the default normal lane
2. The right lane is easy for me to join as it is near for me, however this is the overtaking lane.

[image: road signs]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with travel, and is thus off-topic. The same question — how to merge — will face every driver following the yellow track, without regard to their residence or travel status.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica There has been a history of road signs and intersections questions on here.

Answer (score 6):

When you get to your red circle, you're likely to have to wait unless the road is very quiet.  This can be a long wait.  Remember you'll be starting from zero speed so if you join the  fast (orange mark) lane, people can be coming up behind you at 70 mph when you're almost stationary, and they won't have much time to react.  So you need to wait until the default (green mark) lane is clear

There are odd exceptions - e.g. when lanes are slowing and about to split or reach a bigger junction, getting in the *appropriate* lane for your destination might be better.

If you want a challenge, arrive at that sort of junction on a bike! I have (and ended up crossing both lanes, pulling up and stopping at the side of the road, then getting going in the next gap, all to travel a few hundred metres down the A road).

Ideally you'd take a different route, car or bike, at busy periods - Google can set you up for tricky/slow junctions like this when following signposts would get you there much more easily.  Sometimes there isn't a better route.  You may even consider turning left and doubling back at the next big junction, in some places (if allowed, e.g. a roundabout)

Comment: +1 from me for the really good recommendation, which is to replan your route so you don't have to do this, at least at busy times.  It makes the journey longer, yes, but it will also make it safer.

Answer (score 5):

You should cross each carriageway separately. The [Highway Code](https://www.highwaycodeuk.co.uk/road-junctions.html) covers this:

> **173 Dual carriageways**. When crossing or turning right, first assess whether the central reservation is deep enough to protect the full length of your vehicle.
>
> - If it is, then you should treat each half of the carriageway as a separate road. Wait in the central reservation until there is a safe gap in the traffic on the second half of the road.
> - If the central reservation is too shallow for the length of your vehicle, wait until you can cross both carriageways in one go.

and

> **180 Turning right**. Wait until there is a safe gap between you and any oncoming vehicle.

So first, wait until the gap in the centre is clear (where your yellow line goes to). Then when it is safe to cross the first carriageway, do so and STOP where your red circle is.

Wait there until it is safe to turn right into fast-moving traffic. Do not attempt to join in the lane you marked orange. Wait until BOTH lanes are clear, turn into the left lane (your green lane) and accelerate up to traffic speed.

Do not be tempted to turn into the orange lane when it is busy. You'll very likely cause a high speed collision. Wait for both lanes to be clear. An exception to this can be when the road is very busy, the traffic speed is slow, and someone *invites* you to join the orange lane in front of them.

Otherwise, you must wait. Traffic usully travels in bunches, and eventually it will be safe for you to join the road.

Comment: +1 from me, for an authoritative quote.